# area limited by curves

Tags: integration, area

help find the integrate for find area.

$$R=\{(x,y)\in R^2: x^2+y^2\geq1, x^2+4y^2\leq 4, x-y\geq0, y\geq 0\}$$

I know what the area is, but I find it difficult to form the integral, can you help me with that?

Comment: *How* do you know what the area is?

Comment: Hints: What shapes do the inequalities represent? Can you express them in polar co-ordinates?

Comment: integrate. any method

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Look at the image below. This is the set $R$. You need to find intersection points of various curves (corners in the picture). The leftmost curve is the circle, the rightmost is the ellipse and the top left corner is the straight line. Now set up the integral with upper-lower curve idea. Hopefully this will help.

[image]